# Scalar function occurring request timeout issue in SQL Server while using in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-functions

This is salar fuction . I am using this in Stored procedure with muliple parameters. For small results it is good but for big data it gets time out and also taking a long execuition time. Please share some other alternate or some enhancements

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[FNGETMULIPLEASSIGNESS_NEW2]
(
  @TIMELINEID INT,
  @MILSTONEID INT,
  @TASKID INT
)

RETURNS varchar(max)
AS
  BEGIN
        DECLARE @Assignees varchar(max)='', @isExists bit=0
   if(@TASKID=0)
        BEGIN
        Select  @Assignees = @Assignees+ FIRSTNAME +' ' + LASTNAME+', '  
            FROM CASETIMELINEPEOPLE 
            INNER JOIN USERDETAIL  ON 
            CASETIMELINEPEOPLE.PEOPLEUSERID=USERDETAIL.USERID
            WHERE (CASETIMELINEID= @TIMELINEID) AND 
            (TEMPLATEMILESTONEID=@MILSTONEID) AND 
            (TEMPLATETASKID is null) and CASETIMELINEPEOPLE.isdeleted=0
    END

  else

        BEGIN
            Select  @Assignees = @Assignees+ FIRSTNAME +' ' + LASTNAME+','  
            FROM CASETIMELINEPEOPLE 
            INNER JOIN USERDETAIL  ON 
            CASETIMELINEPEOPLE.PEOPLEUSERID=USERDETAIL.USERID
            WHERE (CASETIMELINEID= @TIMELINEID) AND 
            (TEMPLATEMILESTONEID=@MILSTONEID) AND 
            (TEMPLATETASKID=@TASKID) and CASETIMELINEPEOPLE.isdeleted=0

       END

        SELECT @Assignees=SUBSTRING(@Assignees, 0,LEN(@Assignees))  
        RETURN @Assignees
END
```

Comment: I see not much alternatives to improve the SELECT. Maybe adding some INDEX by the referenced fields to the tables could help.

Comment: You can avoid the if/else by `WHERE COALESCE(TEMPLATETASKID, 0) = @TASKID` (or just an ordinary OR in the condition)

Comment: Thanks Galcoholic . Indexing was missing there

Answer (score 3):

Using an inline table valued function will improve performance.

Reference:

- [When is a SQL function not a function? "If it’s not inline, it’s rubbish." - Rob Farley](http://blogs.lobsterpot.com.au/2011/11/08/when-is-a-sql-function-not-a-function/)
- [Inline Scalar Functions - Itzik Ben-Gan](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/inline-scalar-functions)
- [Scalar functions, inlining, and performance: An entertaining title for a boring post - Adam Machanic](http://dataeducation.com/scalar-functions-inlining-and-performance-an-entertaining-title-for-a-boring-post/)
- [TSQL User-Defined Functions: Ten Questions You Were Too Shy To Ask - Robert Sheldon](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/sql-training/tsql-user-defined-functions-ten-questions-you-were-too-shy-to-ask/)

---

Here is an inline table valued function version of your scalar function that uses the [**`stuff()`** with **`select ... for xml path ('')`** method of string concatenation](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/).:

```
create function dbo.fn_get_multiple_assigness_itvf (
    @timelineid int
  , @milstoneid int
  , @taskid int
) returns table as return (
select Assignees = stuff((
    select ',' + firstname + ' ' + lastname
    from casetimelinepeople ctp
      inner join userdetail ud
        on ctp.peopleuserid=ud.userid
    where casetimelineid = @timelineid
      and templatemilestoneid = @milstoneid
      and (templatetaskid = @taskid 
        or (@taskid = 0 and templatetaskid is null)
        )
      and ctp.isdeleted=0
    for xml path (''), type).value('.','nvarchar(max)')
  ,1,1,'')
)
go
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/UZTJS46485

test setup:

```
create table casetimelinepeople (
    casetimelineid int
  , peopleuserid int
  , templatemilestoneid int
  , templatetaskid int
  , isdeleted bit not null default 0
);
insert into casetimelinepeople values
 (1,1,1,null,0)
,(1,2,1,null,0)
,(1,3,1,null,0)
,(1,2,1,1,0)
,(1,3,1,1,0)

create table userdetail (
    userid int not null
  , firstname varchar(32) not null
  , lastname varchar(32) not null);
insert into userdetail values
 (1, 'Some', 'One')
,(2, 'Avinash', 'Raikwar')
,(3, 'Sql','Zim');
go
```

And querying the inline table valued function like so:

```
select * 
from dbo.fn_get_multiple_assigness_itvf(1,1,0)
```

returns

```
+----------------------------------+
|            Assignees             |
+----------------------------------+
| Some One,Avinash Raikwar,Sql Zim |
+----------------------------------+
```

---

```
select * 
from dbo.fn_get_multiple_assigness_itvf(1,1,1)
```

returns:

```
+-------------------------+
|        Assignees        |
+-------------------------+
| Avinash Raikwar,Sql Zim |
+-------------------------+
```

---

Using [**`cross apply()`**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx) to call the function for each row in a query:

```
select *
from casetimelinepeople ctp
  cross apply dbo.fn_get_multiple_assigness_itvf(
      ctp.casetimelineid
    , ctp.templatemilestoneid
    , ctp.templatetaskid
    ) x
```

returns:

```
+----------------+--------------+---------------------+----------------+-----------+----------------------------------+
| casetimelineid | peopleuserid | templatemilestoneid | templatetaskid | isdeleted |            Assignees             |
+----------------+--------------+---------------------+----------------+-----------+----------------------------------+
|              1 |            1 |                   1 | NULL           | False     | Some One,Avinash Raikwar,Sql Zim |
|              1 |            2 |                   1 | NULL           | False     | Some One,Avinash Raikwar,Sql Zim |
|              1 |            3 |                   1 | NULL           | False     | Some One,Avinash Raikwar,Sql Zim |
|              1 |            2 |                   1 | 1              | False     | Avinash Raikwar,Sql Zim          |
|              1 |            3 |                   1 | 1              | False     | Avinash Raikwar,Sql Zim          |
+----------------+--------------+---------------------+----------------+-----------+----------------------------------+
```

Comment: That Article by Rob Farley is excellent. Thanks for posting it.

Comment: @AlanBurstein glad you enjoyed it!